# Firebase cloud messaging not working since 26th September 2017,Suddenly stopped working, any idea?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My application have firebase cloud messaging service working fine but Firebase cloud messaging not working since 26th September 2017,Suddenly stopped working, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many tries I simply updated firebase service from gradle file to latest version, and it worked.